# JaxRs use interface as parameter

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I use JavaEE 8 on my own project .
is any way to use interface as parameter in JaxRs ?
for example if i have a interface like this :

```
public interface Thing {
      // Without any method .
}
```

and two implementation of this :

```
public class Car implements Thing {
    private String name ;
    private String model ;
}

public class AirPlan implements Thing {
    private String name ;
    private String model  ;
    private long age ;
}
```

I want to declare api with factory as parameter like this :

```
@Path("/create")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response createThing(Thing thing) {
       // execute some operations ....
}
```

if client send name,model,age as parameters this method create AirPlan object and if client send only name,model as Parameters this method create Car object .

**UPDATE**
I have this update on question :
change Thing to class .

```
public class Thing {
    private String type ; 
}
```

and extend other class from this .

Now :

```
@Path("/create")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response createThing(Thing thing) {
       // execute some operations ....
}
```

create Car if `type=="car"` or create Airplan if `type=="airplan"`

Comment: I update question . Thank you .

Comment: You need to look at the documentation of the JSON library you chose to use with Jersey to know how it can handle such polymorphic deserialization.